# asp.net dynamic control and jquery

Tags: asp.net

I have some controls being dynamically added to the placeholder control and on the page it has the HTML button (not asp button) that does the validation on the dynamic controls. And the click event handler of the HTML button is in the .js file.

Can anyone suggest the best method to do this?

Comment: what is the problem you are having?  client validation will work the same regardless of if the controls are dynamic or static.

Answer (score 1):

Since I see that you're already using jQuery in your project I recommend you this validation library

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Very flexible and easy to use.

Comment: Hi.. I also need to collect the values as it will be stored in the database.